# AjaxPro não acessível no IIS

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net, iis, ajaxtoolkit

Tenho uma aplicação simples com WebForms, criei alguns métodos que irei acessar por Ajax via AjaxPro DLL.

Utilizei o atributo `[AjaxPro.AjaxNamespace("Teste")]` na classe e o `[AjaxPro.AjaxMethod]` no metodo.

Fiz o registro da classe no AjaxPro `AjaxPro.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(Teste))`

No javascript defini a chamada do metodo `Teste.MetodoTeste().value`

E no web.config defini a configuração do AjaxPro desta maneira:

```
<add verb="POST,GET" path="/ajaxpro/*.ashx" name="AjaxPro" type="AjaxPro.AjaxHandlerFactory,AjaxPro" />
```

No próprio Visual Studio, quando eu executo a aplicação, utilizando o IIS Express, o método é chamado corretamente e consigo pegar o retorno tranquilamente.

A questão é, por que quando eu publico a aplicação no IIS Local o sistema não localiza mais o AjaxPro?

Recebo vários erros:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

e

> Index.aspx:66 Uncaught ReferenceError: Teste is not defined(…)

no console do navegador.

Comment: Você não esqueceu de registrar o tipo da sua classe para o `AjaxPro`?
Exemplo:  `Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(Teste), Page)`

Comment: Eu registrei, desculpe esqueci de dizer. Porem foi diferente da sua sugestão: AjaxPro.Utility.RegisterTypeForAjax(typeof(Teste));

Comment: A DLL foi enviada na hora de publicação?

Comment: Sim, a Ajaxpro.dll está na pasta bin do projeto no diretorio virtual que o IIS criou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido!

No web.config a configuração do ajaxpro estava da seguinte maneira:

```
<add verb="POST,GET" path="/ajaxpro/*.ashx" name="AjaxPro" type="AjaxPro.AjaxHandlerFactory,AjaxPro" />
```

Fiz um ajuste na tag path e a aplicação passou a funcionar no IIS Local e no IIS Express:

```
<add verb="POST,GET" path="*.ashx" name="AjaxPro" type="AjaxPro.AjaxHandlerFactory,AjaxPro" />
```